# import bd phpmyadmin 000webhost.com error #1044

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a localhost db, and i want to import it to my phpmyadmin 000webhost.com db. Maybe i don't have privilegies.
[image]

SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `RF_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'id1302584_grigorie'@'%' to database 'RF_db'

Comment: first of all, stay away from 000webhost. they are bad. And my guess is that you do NOT have access to create databases. Use a real webhosting provider or run it locally.

Comment: It is literally telling you that you don't have access. What is your question?

Comment: PHP questions are questions involving PHP code. For applications (phpmyadmin) using PHP please don't tag PHP.